# implementing Vector of vectors

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I am actually operating on vector of vectors. but how do i increment the row and column pointer(here pointer means iterator) 
My code is like

```
bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {

    vector< vector<int> >::iterator row=matrix.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator col=row->begin();

    while(row!=matrix.end()&&col!=row->end())
    {
        if(*col==target)
            return true;
        else
        {
            if(*(col)+1<=target)
                ++col;
            else
                ++row;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And what is your problem?

Comment: As is, this is a very strange search. You should state the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search the whole matrix you need to have 2 loops: outer for rows and inner for columns -- this looks more obvious.

```
bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
    for (vector< vector<int> >::iterator row=matrix.begin(); row != matrix.end(); ++row) {
       for (vector<int>::iterator col=row->begin(); col != col.end(); ++col){
          if(*col==target)
             return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

...but this approach is better when all your rows are of different length. If this is a rectangular matrix it's better to keep it all in a single vector of length `row * col`
You may write accessor method for it (I'll bring non-template method to not overcomplicate) if you like:

```
int& getElement(<vector<int>& matrix, size_t matrixWidth, size_t row, size_t col)
{
   // here's no boundary check!!!
   return matrix[row * matrixWidth + col];
}
```

In this case your search becomes simple:

```
bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
    for (vector<int>::iterator item=matrix.begin(); item != matrix.end(); ++item){
        if(*item==target)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using iterators, rather than indexes to give the position within a vector is largely a style choice.  If vector of vector is a decent choice for your data structure (a separate question) and your desired algorithm is as shown, then you have hit the limits of your style choice and it is time to drop style and focus on function.

Phrased more simply:  Don't uses iterators, use indexes.

```
bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {

    std::size_t row=0;
    std::size_t col=0;

    while(row!=matrix.size()&&col<matrix[row].size())
    {
        if(matrix[row][col]==target)
            return true;
        else
        {
            if(matrix[row][col]+1<=target)
                ++col;
            else
                ++row;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```